# PyCharm起動時に"Scanning Installed Packages"が表示されて、先に進まない

Tags: pycharm

## 環境

- Windows 10
- conda 4.6.2
- PyCharm 2018.3.5 (Community Edition)

```
Build #PC-183.5912.18, built on February 26, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b28 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

- java 1.8.0_162

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

## 問題

PyCharmでPyCharm用のプロジェクトを開くと、"Scanning Installed Packages"が表示されますが、5分以上待ってもこのメッセージが消えません。

[image: PyCharm]

タスクマネージャのプロセスから"conda.exe"を終了したら、"Scanning Installed Packages"が消えて、PyCharmを操作することができました。

[image: タスクマネージャ]

## 質問

"Scanning Installed Packages"が終わらない問題を、根本的に解決するには、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私も同じ状況になりましたが、下記のサポートページを参考に

> **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**

をしたら直りました。

[Stuck 'Scanning Installed Packages' – IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform) | JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003055399-Stuck-Scanning-Installed-Packages-)

Answer (score 0):

JetBrainsのフォーラムにも似たような質問がありました。

[Stuck 'Scanning Installed Packages' – IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform) \| JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003055399-Stuck-Scanning-Installed-Packages-)

最新版のJavaをインストールすると解消した、とあるのでJavaを最新版に更新してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: PyCharmをインストールする際Javaのインストールは不要と書いてあります。JavaのUpdateとPyCharmが関係するのでしょうか？
また、Javaを1.8からいくつにバージョンアップすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: >JRE 1.8 is bundled with the PyCharm distribution. You do not need to install Java on your computer to run PyCharm. For specific Python development, you may need to install Jython, PyPy, or IronPython.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/install-and-set-up-pycharm.html

Comment: PyCharm自体がJavaで動作するIDEなので、関係自体はあります。が、正直なところ、本当にUpdateが有効かどうかはわかりません（私は同じ事象に遭遇していないため）。可能性の一つとして試してみては、と思い回答した次第です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: ちなみに、以下のサイトを参考に、`Mark as Directory As > Excluded`で、不要なディレクトリを除外してみましたが、解決しませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976058/pycharm-5-0-1-scanning-files-to-index-taking-forever/34976320